# How to add another table inside a datatable when clicked on a row - LWC

Tags: lightning-datatable, datatable, table, accordion, lightningtreegrid

I have a requirement to open another table on click of a lightning datatable's row accordion.I already have the datatable code present in which I have used Basic Lightning datatable.Now the requirement is,I have to add accordions to all the rows and on click of any accordion that particular records value should be shown.

[image: This is my Table before clicking on the accordion]

[image: This is my Table after clicking on the accordion]

Image 1:This is my Table before clicking on the accordion

Image 2:This is my Table after clicking on the accordion

My current code just consists of normal lightning datatable:

```
            <lightning-datatable
                      key-field="id"
                      hide-checkbox-column="true"
                      row-number-offset="0"
                      show-row-number-column
                      columns={subsection.columnList}
                      data={subsection.columnData}
                      default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
                      sorted-direction={subsection.sortDirection}
                      sorted-by={subsection.sortBy}
                      onsort={onHandleSort}
                      name={subsection.Header}
                      data-table-id={subsection.subHeader}
                      column-widths-mode="fixed">
              </lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: You can't do that with lightning-datatable. You may want to look at lightning-tree-grid.